# Block https by mac address. Squid or iptables

Tags: iptables, squid, webfilter

I want to block web access (http and https) to certain mac addresses. I was able to do this for http using squid but it still lets https sites through.

```
acl denylist arp "/etc/squid/mac-deny-list.lst
http_access deny denylist
```

How can I do the same for https/443?

I've tried using iptables

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j DROP
```

and

```
 iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j DROP
```

I've also tried using `REJECT` instead of `DROP`. Neither is working.

The rest of my iptables rules are:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [467:49957]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4:784]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:960]
-A PREROUTING -i eth1.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128 
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [122012:18388989]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [10802:1834986]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1807836:1494699352]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5667 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
```

#### Update

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 334 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   41  2624 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
  386 42629 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
60371 5794K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
6558K 2220M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5667 
60264 3616K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5666 
    3   211 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:161 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth1.10 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
  61M   46G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
48857 3337K ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW 
 159K   17M ACCEPT     all  --  eth1.10 eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 49 packets, 6584 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

#### TCPDUMP (truncated)

```
tcpdump -e -i eth1.10 '!(host 10.15.248.122)' and 'ether host 00:60:dd:44:85:43'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1.10, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
14:01:47.452656 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 116: resolver1.opendns.com.domain > 172.31.235.114.63561: 6769 2/0/0 CNAME star.c10r.facebook.com., A 31.13.77.6 (74)
14:01:47.470098 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [S.], seq 2645004585, ack 3584915781, win 14100, options [mss 1410,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 8], length 0
14:01:47.485180 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], ack 518, win 67, length 0
14:01:47.485398 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 236: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [P.], seq 1:183, ack 518, win 67, length 182
14:01:47.500703 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], ack 634, win 67, length 0
14:01:47.500891 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 111: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [P.], seq 183:240, ack 634, win 67, length 57
14:01:47.503275 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], ack 691, win 67, length 0
14:01:47.503302 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], ack 736, win 67, length 0
14:01:47.503372 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], ack 1181, win 78, length 0
14:01:47.503585 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 99: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [P.], seq 240:285, ack 1181, win 78, length 45
14:01:47.566820 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1464: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], seq 285:1695, ack 1181, win 78, length 1410
14:01:47.566838 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 266: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [P.], seq 1695:1907, ack 1181, win 78, length 212
14:01:47.566965 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1464: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], seq 1907:3317, ack 1181, win 78, length 1410
14:01:47.567072 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1282: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [P.], seq 3317:4545, ack 1181, win 78, length 1228
14:01:47.569446 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1464: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], seq 4545:5955, ack 1181, win 78, length 1410
14:01:47.569562 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1464: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], seq 5955:7365, ack 1181, win 78, length 1410
14:01:47.569682 00:08:54:23:fa:93 (oui Unknown) > 00:60:dd:44:85:43 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1464: edge-star-shv-01-sjc2.facebook.com.https > 172.31.235.114.50452: Flags [.], seq 7365:8775, ack 1181, win 78, length 1410
```

@Matt

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue May 12 14:44:35 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [53:6397]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [822:337604]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5667 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source 00:60:DD:44:85:43 -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May 12 14:44:35 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue May 12 14:44:35 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [325:31771]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [16:1474]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [308:20843]
-A PREROUTING -i eth1.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128 
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May 12 14:44:35 2015
```

#### Interface Details

```
eth0 - 192.168.2.22 (/24) (public/outside/NAT) 
eth1.10 - 172.31.235.19 (/24) (private/inside/vlan10)
```

Comment: To filter on MAC Address using `iptables`, clients and firewall interface have to be on the same network segment. If you have routing somewhere this will not work.

Comment: eth1.10 and the computer with the mac I want blocked are on the same subnet.

Comment: Ok great ! so this should work : `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -p tcp --destination-port 443 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:X:X -j DROP`.

Comment: @krisFR Right, which is why I used `I` and not `A` to put the rule at the top. It is not working, and nor does your command above.

Comment: Post `iptables -L -n -v` once you have applied the rule.

Comment: @krisFR There you go.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could also post a `tcpdump` trace while client with MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is making an https request ?

Comment: After inserting the rule, run iptables-save and dump the output.  I think perhaps you've got the rule in the wrong place.

Comment: Why does eth0 have a non internet routeable address? or is this part of an internal network?

Comment: @Matt Because it routes to another internal network before it reaches our internet gateway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the MAC filter rule is processed after accepting it.  So it is never reached.

What you need to do is change the order of these two lines:

```
  -A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
  -A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source 00:60:DD:44:85:43 -j DROP
```

So they become:

```
-A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source 00:60:DD:44:85:43 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth1.10 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

If you use iptables-save format you'd just edit the output of iptables-save and run iptables-restore passing in that file.  i.e.

```
sudo iptables-save > rules

... edit 'rules'

sudo iptables-restore < rules
```

Or alternatively, just edit whatever script/generator you are using to create the rules.

> Note: Since you're filtering internal addresses, I'd use REJECT rather
>   than DROP or otherwise the user may not realise they have been blocked
>   and be wondering why their browser just sits there for a very long
>   time.

Comment: I'll test this out tonight and get back to you. Good point about the order.

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: What are you using to insert your rules into the kernel? iptables command, scripts or another tool?

Comment: iptables commands.

Comment: If you're running them in a script, please post the entire script.  Also please clearly state which are the public and private interfaces and what IP's they should have just to be sure.

Comment: Added that info the the question and no I'm not using a script. I'm using iptables commands.

Comment: If you're not running a script, how are you populating the kernel tables on startup?

Comment: like `iptables -I INPUT...` then `service iptables save`.

Comment: I suggest you start with no rules at.  Add a log rule and then a block rule.  And mess around with it till you get a match.  The logging will tell you how the kernel sees it and will help you to create the right match so you can drop it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually need to put MAC filter in the PREROUTING chain because of the way iptables re-writes some fields internally.

From [Chain traversal for routing, when the bridge and netfilter code are compiled in the kernel](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section9)

> The side effect explained here occurs when the netfilter code is enabled in the kernel, the IP packet is routed and the out device for that packet is a logical bridge device. The side effect is encountered when filtering on the MAC source in the iptables FORWARD chains. As should be clear from earlier sections, the traversal of the iptables FORWARD chains is postponed until the packet is in the bridge code. This is done so we can filter on the bridge port out device. This has a side effect on the MAC source address, because the IP code will have changed the MAC source address to the MAC address of the bridge device.

Comment: Tried that with `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth1.10 -p tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source 00:60:dd:44:85:43 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128`. Still allowing that mac to connect to website using https.

Comment: why did you use that on the nat table?

Comment: @Matt What's your suggestion?

Comment: omit the "-t nat"

Comment: If I omit the `-t nat`: `iptables -I PREROUTING -i eth1.10 -p tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source 00:60:dd:44:85:43 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128`
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: It wouldn't be as simple as case sensitivity on the alpha characters?  Have you tried with capital Ds?  There is also arptables filtering instead of iptables. I've never used it, but that may work instead.